# error writing with FIFO's the terminal just hangs no output

Tags: linux, g++, fifo

i am trying to read and write between two processes using FIFOs but when i open a FIFO it doesnt print any message that i have given it to print similarly when I write to it it aslo doesnt display anything ...so how  am I suppose to know if its working or not? why does it hang in the terminal it just keeps taking input and doesnt end?please help me out here I think the code is correct but here it goes

```
int  main ()

{
    int fd;
    char  buffer[MAX];
    char * os;
    if(mkfifo("oss",0666)<0)
    {
        perror("FIFO (named pipe) could not be created.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else printf("\nPipe has been created...");
    fd=open ("oss", O_WRONLY);
    if (fd <0)
    {
        perror("Could not open named pipe.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else printf("Pipe has been opened.");
     strcpy(buffer,"please connect :( ");

    if( write (fd,buffer, strlen(buffer)+1) < 0 )
    {
      perror("Error writing to named Pipe (FIFO)");
      exit(-1);
    }
    else 
        printf("Message has been written to pipe.");
```

i am using g++ on linux

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing to know about FIFOs is that the `open()` syscall blocks until someone attempts to open the same FIFO for the other direction.

You cannot open a FIFO for writing, write something in it and close it and later open it for reading and retrieve the data. It has to be opened for reading and writing simultaneously, because it's a named PIPE.

Your program is probably hanging at line

```
fd=open ("oss", O_WRONLY);
```

as it's waiting for someone to open the FIFO for reading.

I learned this when writing a daemon controlled by commands written into a FIFO. I spent a day totally baffled and then read

```
man 2 open
```

which gave a hint to

```
man 7 fifo
```

where I found the solution.